# Is this the correct way to Unit test the repository using mocks?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, repository-pattern

I have this `UserRepository` class.

```
public class UserRepo : IUserRepo 
{
    public TheUser RegisterUser(UserRegistrationDetails details)
    {
        //implementation here
    }

    public bool DeleteUser(string username)
    {
        //implementation here
    }

    public TheUser UpdateUser(TheUser user)
    {
        //implementation here
    }
 }
```

Now to test this I created a mock repository by implementing the same interface `IUserRepo` and my test class now calls this Mock repository.  I feel I am doing something wrong here as I have not tested the actual `UserRepository` class but another mocked up implementation of it. How should I correct this? Is the Repository tested at all?

Comment: I suggest using a mocking framework like Moq to instantiate mock classes based on your interfaces saving you the time of rolling your own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use your mocked `IUserRepo` to test classes that consume an `IUserRepo`, not to test the implementation of `UserRepo`.

```
public class Consumer
{
  private IUserRepo repo;  

  public Consumer(IUserRepo repo)
  {
    this.repo = repo;
  }

  public void DoStuff()
  { 
    // Act upon repository
  }
}
```

You would be able to test `Consumer` using your Mocked repository, isolating it from any (for example) db calls.

To unit test `UserRepo` itself, you would pass in **it's** dependencies

```
public class UserRepo : IUserRepo 
{
   private ISomeDependancy dependancy;

   public UserRepo(ISomeDependancy dependancy)
   {
      this.dependancy = dependancy;
   }

   public TheUser RegisterUser(UserRegistrationDetails details)
   {
       //implementation here, that consumes this.dependancy
   }

   ....
```

And apply the same theory as above.